Gammu SMSD: "DBI Error -6" While Using libdbi
Gammu SMSD: "DBI Error -6: An invalid or out-of-range index was passed to libdbi"
I am running Gammu SMSD on my Raspberry Pi with a sqlite3 database which I copied from the gammu /examples folder.
I see following error in the logs:
DBI error -6: -6: An invalid or out-of-range index was passed to libdbi
Here are the details of my setup:
Database: sqlite3
Gammu Configuration (gammu-smsdrc):
[gammu]
device = /dev/ttyUSB2
connection = at

[smsd]
service = sql
driver = sqlite3
dbdir = /home/mark/Repositories/sms-gateway
database = sms_gateway.db
logfile = /var/log/gammu-smsd.log

[Gammu version 1.42.0]
libdbi1 (Shared Library): 0.9.0-6
libdbi-perl (Perl Interface): 1.643-4
libdbi-dev (Development Files): 0.9.0-6
libdbd-sqlite3 (SQLite3 Driver): 0.9.0-11

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.
